# Changing the colors of each of the Stacked Bar chart with different Color in D3

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

This involved the assignment of different colors to each bars of the stacked bar charts as currently there is only single color in all the four bars and colors are changing in the stacked one but I am trying to assign different colors to all the four bars as well the stacked value.

Here is the code

```
    var margin = {
            top: 20,
            right: 160,
            bottom: 35,
            left: 30
          };

          var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

          var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


          /* Data in strings like it would be if imported from a csv */

          var data = [{
              year: "A",
              redDelicious: "10",
              mcintosh: "5",
              oranges: "19"
            }, {
              year: "B",
              redDelicious: "12",
              mcintosh: "0",
              oranges: "15"
            }, {
              year: "C",
              redDelicious: "05",
              mcintosh: "0",
              oranges: "28"
            }, {
              year: "D",
              redDelicious: "14",
              mcintosh: "0",
              oranges: "12"
            },

          ];
          $("#btn").on("click", function(){
            d3.selectAll("svg > g > g").remove();
            data[1].mcintosh = (Number(data[1].mcintosh) + 1).toString();
            console.log(1,data);
            update();
          });
          update();
    function update(){
          var orangeData = data.map(function(d) {
            return {
              year: d.year,
              oranges: +d.oranges
            }
          });
          console.log(orangeData)



          // Transpose the data into layers
          var dataset = d3.layout.stack()(["redDelicious", "mcintosh"].map(function(skillset) {
            return data.map(function(d) {
              return {
                x: d.year,
                y: +d[skillset]
              };
            });
          }));
          console.log(dataset)

          // Set x, y and colors
          var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(dataset[0].map(function(d) {
              return d.x;
            }))
            .rangeRoundBands([10, width - 10], 0.02);

          var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
              return d3.max(d, function(d) {
                return d.y0 + d.y;
              });
            })])
            .range([height, 0]);

          var colors = ["#b33040", "#d9d574"];
           var backcolors = ["red", "blue","green","pink"];


          // Define and draw axes
          var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .orient("left")
            .ticks(5)
            .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
            .tickFormat(function(d) {
              return d
            });

          var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom");
          //  .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y"));

          svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis);

          svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

            // Creating the Average Bar for the Semester
            svg.selectAll(".bar1").data(orangeData).enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "bar1").append("rect")
            .attr("x", function(d) {
              return x(d.year) ; // center it
            })
            .attr("width", x.rangeBand()) // make it slimmer
            .attr("y", function(d) {
              return y(d.oranges);
            })
            .attr("height", function(d) {
              return height - y(d.oranges);
            });



          // Create groups for each series, rects for each segment in Stacked Bar 
          var groups = svg.selectAll("g.cost")
            .data(dataset)
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "cost")
            .style("fill", function(d, i) {
              return colors[i];
            });

          var rect = groups.selectAll("rect")
            .data(function(d) {
              return d;
            })
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("x", function(d) {
              return x(d.x)  + 20 ;
            })
            .attr("y", function(d) {
              return y(d.y0 + d.y);
            })
            .attr("height", function(d) {
              return y(d.y0) - y(d.y0 + d.y);
            })
            .attr("width", x.rangeBand() -40 );
            }
```

Here is the working [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/hawkeye15/omwo8qbo/4/)

Comment: The question is not clear. Do you want a rainbow like this? https://fiddle.jshell.net/md51wruc/

Comment: Yeah its right but I want to choose my own set of colors.

Comment: For each one of the 8 bars in the stacked bars?

Comment: yeah, so basically I need 8 different colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, set your colours array:

```
var colors = ['#7fc97f','#beaed4','#fdc086','#ffff99','#386cb0','#f0027f','#bf5b17','#666666'];
```

Then, in your rectangles (not in your groups), set the fill of each bar using the parent's index:

```
.attr("fill", function(d, i, j) {
      return colors[(j*4)+i];
 });
```

Here, the magic number "4" is the number of groups. Change it accordingly (if you create more bars).

Here is your fiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/747beqqc/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was not aware of this "j" variable that I can create to run the loop so that next bar access to the another set of colors. 
Thanks, it helped a lot. :)