# How to do data map / array properly to get different colors? D3.js

Tags: d3.js

I have searched and am confused.

My graph has a couple regular bars and a stacked bar with 5 different values. I want all of them to be different colors, so 7 different colors.

To start with, I was just trying to put one color per bar (and ignore the stacked bar). I am using V4.

```
var data = [
  {month: "june", a: 500, color: 'green'},
  {month: "july", a: 90, b: 90, c: 90, d: 90, e: 90, color: 'orange'},
  {month: "august", a: 240, color: 'red'}
];

var series = d3.stack()
    .keys(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "color"])
    .offset(d3.stackOffsetDiverging)
    (data);
```

Then I am trying to reference it this way.

```
.attr("fill", data.map(function(d) { return d.color; }))
```

Obviously that is wrong because I get no color. Tried some other things too.

What I really is something like this for the stacked bar (or all three) but I want to hardcode the colors and not have it color based on value ranges.

```
d3.scale.ordinal().range(["hexcolor1", "hexcolor2", "hexcolor3", "hexcolor4", "hexcolor5"]).range()
```

Found this to answer part of my question: [Changing the colors of each of the Stacked Bar chart with different Color in D3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39978657/changing-the-colors-of-each-of-the-stacked-bar-chart-with-different-color-in-d3)

My regular bars (I have some non-stacked bars) all get the first color in my color array. My stacked bar gets the different colors in my array.

Fiddle links are expired, but the OP mentioned "another set of colors"? I am not sure if your code was only for repeating colors. I want something like: red bar (not stacked), green bar (not stacked), purple/pink/yellow/orange bar, blue bar (not stacked).

Edit: Actually I get no color (all black) when I put in the j code.

```
var data = [
  {month: "mike", a: 500},
  {month: "judy", a: 90, b: 90, c: 90, d: 90},
  {month: "matt", a: 240}
];

var mycolors = ['#386cb0','#487cc0','#589cd0','#988cf0'];

var mycolorsb = ['#FFFF00'];

var series = d3.stack()
    .keys(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "color"])
    .offset(d3.stackOffsetDiverging)
    (data);

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 60, left: 130},
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

var y = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.month; }))
    .rangeRound([margin.top, height - margin.bottom])

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0,1000])
    .rangeRound([margin.left, width - margin.right]);

svg.append("g")
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(series)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr ("fill", function(d, i, j) { return mycolors[(j*4)+i]; })
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) { return d; })
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("height", 75)
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.data.month); })
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d[0]); })
    .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d[1]) - x(d[0]); })
```

Also I tried to do something like this code:
[d3.js-adding different colors to one bar in stacked bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45280898/d3-js-adding-different-colors-to-one-bar-in-stacked-bar-chart) but it doesn't seem to work the way I did it. The matt bar still gets the same first color in the array.

```
.attr("fill", function(d, i, j) { return d.month === "matt" ? mycolorsb[i] : mycolors[i]; })
```

I would be ok with replacing/overwriting the color after it's created since it's only 2 or 3 non-stacked bars. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: First of all, you're mixing v3 and v4/5 syntaxes. What's exactly the version you're using? Second, your stack generator won't work with that data. Finally, please explain your goal better: you want *every* bar in a different colour, regardless the group or the variable, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, every bar would be different. (Not random but specified.)

I abandoned trying to do the data.map and d3.scale.ordinal after I found your other code below.

Comment: Deleted the "answer". I've been using V4. There's a lot I don't know. Desired outcome is mike bar is orange, judy stacked bar is 4 different blues/purples, matt bar is red.