# d3 Stacked Bar chart - assign olors

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have created a stacked bar chart using d3 and now I am trying to specify custom colors for the bars. Here is what I've tried [based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39978996/2827407)(the colors are all set to black current just so I can make sure its working):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<svg id="chart" width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var data = [
  {month: "January", toys: 16591, games: 1047, books: 0, crafts: 5757},
  {month: "February", toys: 42337, games: 129, books: 835, crafts: 0},
  {month: "March", toys:  3385, games: 1053, books: 6260, crafts: 10},
  {month: "April", toys:  353, games: 3724, books: 4038, crafts: 0}
];

var series = d3.stack()
    .keys(["toys", "games", "books", "crafts"])
    .offset(d3.stackOffsetDiverging)
    (data);

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60},
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.month; }))
    .rangeRound([margin.left, width - margin.right])
    .padding(0.1);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([d3.min(series, stackMin), d3.max(series, stackMax)])
    .rangeRound([height - margin.bottom, margin.top]);

var z = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var colors = ['#000','#000','#000','#000'];

svg.append("g")
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(series)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); })
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) { return d; })
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth)
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data.month); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); })
    .attr("fill", function(d, i, j) {
      return colors[(j*4)+i];
    });

svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + y(0) + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ",0)")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

function stackMin(serie) {
  return d3.min(serie, function(d) { return d[0]; });
}

function stackMax(serie) {
  return d3.max(serie, function(d) { return d[1]; });
}

</script>
```

Clearly this is not working as the default colors are still being shown

Answer (score 0):

There might be two errors on your code, you have two `attr('fill'`.

The first one is

`.attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); })`

And if you would like to use the second one,check the value of `j` in the following lines, I haven't reproduced your code, but I checked a similar code and `j` is the DOM element, so the result of `j*4` might be resulting in `NaN`.

```
`.attr("fill", function(d, i, j) {
  return colors[(j*4)+i];
});`
```